# How to read a sensor in a JobIntentService?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, android-sensors, android-8.0-oreo, jobintentservice

I'm writing an Android app targeting 8 Oreo starting from API level 19. I want to query the data of `Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER`. Since to my understanding there is no way to read the current value directly, I have to create a SensorEventListener wait for a `onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event)`. How do I do this properly in a `JobIntentService`?
Since `onHandleWork(@NonNull Intent intent)` is meant to do a job and then finish, my current solution is to block the thread:

```
/// we need to wait for the sensor to return it's data in onSensorChanged
while (isWaitingForSensor) {
    /// block the thread to not end the Job
    try {
        Thread.sleep(SLEEP_TIME_MS);
        waitTime += SLEEP_TIME_MS;
        if (waitTime >= MAX_WAIT_TIME) {
            isWaitingForSensor = false;
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
    }
}
```

and further in my `SensorEventListener`:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    int stepCount = event.values[0];
    ...
    isWaitingForSensor = false;
}
```

Does somebody have a better and saver solution to this?

Comment: Don't use `JobIntentService`. Either use a regular `Service` (so you can control the service lifetime) or use a `JobService` (where you can fork your own thread and report when your work is done).

Comment: Thank you, JobService seems like a good solution. I failed to mention that I'm aiming to support API level 19.

Comment: Then use a regular `Service`, so you can control the service lifetime.